# How would I simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I am doing this question, and I need to simplify the following in order for me to complete the question. Have I done anything wrong below?

Given $\left(\frac{1}{7\alpha\sqrt\pi}\right)^{1/2}$, $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{h}{mw}}$, am I correct to simplify it to:

$$\left(\frac{1}{7\sqrt{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)^{1/2}$$

and can I write it as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)^{1/2}$$ and further simplifying it:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left(\left({{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)^{-1/2}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left({{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)^{-1/4}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left(\frac{1}{\left({{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)^{1/4}}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left(\frac{1}{\left({{\frac{h\pi}{mw}}}\right)}\right)^{1/4}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\left(\frac{mw}{h\pi}\right)^{1/4}$$

Comment: Why did you remove most of the question? The answer that you accepted no longer makes sense now. In this particular case I don't see any reason for making this change; if you do need to make changes to questions, please mark them clearly as edits if they make one of the answers appear wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you wrote is correct, though you could have proceeded directly from 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\left(\frac{h\pi}{mw}\right)^{-1/4}
$$
to
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\left(\frac{mw}{h\pi}\right)^{1/4}.
$$
A negative exponent on a fraction results in "flipping" the fraction. You don't need to form a compound fraction every time you wish to change the sign of an exponent.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yeah Im doing quite a long question so I just wanted to make sure I did it correctly before proceeding.